# SwiftUI Textfield Padding when Keyboard is in view

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, textfield, ios14

I have a Scrollview with just textfields in it. I want to be able to tap on any textfield and have the keyboard push it up slightly.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                Group {
                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    TextField("Enter stuff", text: $vm.username)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when there's no padding/styling in the textfield. If I use a custom textfield with styling (borders, padding), the keyboard hovers over part of the textfield. This is my custom textfield:

```
struct NotesField: View {
    @Binding var value: String

    init(_ value: Binding<String>) {
        self._value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter stuff", text: $value)
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}
```

It's well known that ios14 handles this for you automatically so I want a solution where I don't have to use a view modifier to listen to when the keyboard is opened or not.

Comment: Do you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iOS 14+ with scrollview or have the option to use scrollview.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewproxy https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader

Below might help

```
    ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
        ScrollView {
            view1().frame(height: 200)
            view2().frame(height: 200)

            view3() <-----this has textfields 
                .onTapGesture {
                    proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .center)
                }
                .id(1)

            view4() <-----this has text editor
                .onTapGesture {
                    proxy.scrollTo(2, anchor: .center)
                }
                .id(2)

            view5().frame(height: 200)
            view6().frame(height: 200)
            submtButton().frame(height: 200)
        }
    }
```

imp part from above is

```
     anyView().onTapGesture {
          proxy.scrollTo(_ID, anchor: .center)
     }.id(_ID)
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: This works perfectly if you use the default textfield but I realized that when you have a custom textfield or textfield with border and padding, it lies on top of the textfield exactly and doesn't push the whole view up